# What are the dependencies for running containers on a system (linux)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, linux-containers

I am new to the world containers, docker, kubernetes and I am investigating requirements for implementing a my middleware distributed project. I took some key container courses with Docker and Kubernetes.
But I would like to ask for those who have more experience, in a production environment (or just execution and instantiation of modules, where each module would be a container) what would be the dependencies to execute a container?

Is it mandatory for me to have the dependency package for docker and docker itself installed for this? To just raise the pods and services with Kubernetes is it also mandatory to have kubectl installed on my host?

Note: For local development and deployment using google cloud I have already done some testing and I know it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To Setup docker on your system you need below things

- if you are going to setup K8s with docker

  1. docker-ce/docker
  2. kubelet
  3. kubectl
  4. curl & wget
- if you are going to setup k8s with minikube

  1. you will need minikube
  2. virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

I feel you need to be more specific what exactly you wanted to know.
There are multiple [container technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization#Implementations) are existing currently. To install docker specifically your linux machine should have **kernel version > 3.10.**
If you want to install Kubernetes on your linux machines

- you need to modify OS level things.(like firewall,swap etc)
- you need to install one of the [container run time](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-runtime) & other kubernetes packages(kubelet kubeadm kubectl ) then setup container networking.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/) you can find clear instructions to install kuberentes via Kubeadm